# Where is my partitioned space?

Tags: partitioning, chromebook, chromeos

I'm very new to Linux. Trying to learn, but curve is kinda steep. So, I loaded Ubuntu 14.04 onto my 16GB Chromebook (HP 14) using the method outlined here http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2013/10/chrubuntu-for-new-chromebooks-now-with.html (side-by-side with Chrome OS, not in shell). I allocated 5G to Ubuntu in setup, but now when I try to downlaod program (specifically, Steam), I'm told I'm out of space (Errno 28). Is space really insufficient, or is something happening with partitions that I don't understand?

```
user@chrubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7       4.8G  4.6G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           390M  1.2M  389M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G   84K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   36K  100M   1% /run/user
overflow        1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /tmp
/dev/sda1       5.6G  507M  4.8G  10% /media/user/2d288a9e-7022-43cd-8240-2b5f5dbf0c24

user@chrubuntu:~$ sudo du -h -d 1
21M ./.cache
28K ./.gconf
4.0K    ./Pictures
628K    ./.local
4.0K    ./Downloads
3.7M    ./.mozilla
4.0K    ./Public
184K    ./.config
4.0K    ./Music
4.0K    ./Documents
4.0K    ./Desktop
4.0K    ./Templates
12K ./.compiz
4.0K    ./Videos
26M .
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wondering where all the space went?  Obviously, it's showing it to be full, and your `du` command shows only the contents of your home directory, which is not where all the space seems to be used.  In order to see the entire filesystem, you need to either start in the root directory (`/`), or add that to the end of the command:  `sudo du -h -d 1 /`

It may take a while to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GParted to see how the space is used (and also to resize your partition, but it's a bit more complicated).
Another good graphical way to see this is using Disk Usage Analyzer.